# Formatting date from JSON response - only shows January?

Tags: java, android, json, date

I am trying to get the right date to display but no matter what I do, or the date, it changes the month to January. What am I doing wrong?

```
  private static String formatDate(String dateFormat) {
    String jsonDate = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(jsonDate, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateFormat);
        String parsedDatePattern = "MM dd y";
        SimpleDateFormat formatJsonDate = new SimpleDateFormat(parsedDatePattern, Locale.getDefault());

        return formatJsonDate.format(parsedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "~*&~*&~*&Error parsing JSON date: ", e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: how does `dateFormat` parameter look like ? What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: `mm` is minutes, `MM` is month. `jsonDate` format is wrong!

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I actually just figured it out, silly mistake!

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" )
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)
.toLocalDate()
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

> 1/23/18

## Case-sensitive

Formatting patterns are case-sensitive.

For month number, use all uppercase `MM`.

Another problem: Your formatting pattern unwisely ignores the `Z` on the end. That letter provides valuable information, indicating UTC, an offset of zero. Pronounced “Zulu”.

## java.time

You are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Your input format is standard ISO 8601 format, used by default in the `Instant` class that replaced `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion, as that is the focus of your Question.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate text representing that date in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

Automatically localize.

```
Locale l = Locale.US ;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l ) ;
String output ld.format( f ) ;
```

Or define your own formatting pattern as shown in many dozens, if not hundreds, of other Answers already posted. Search for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).